# RegEx negative lookahead on pattern

Tags: regex

I want to find all expressions that don't end with ":"
I tried to do it like that:

```
[a-z]{2,}(?!:)
```

On this text:

```
foobar foobaz:
foobaz
foobaz:
```

The problem is, that it just takes away the last character befor the ":" and not the whole match.
Here is the example: https://regex101.com/r/jtLRvz/1

How can I get the negative lookahead work for the whole regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `[a-z]{2,}(?!:)` matches `baz:`, `[a-z]{2,}` grabs 2 or more lowercase ASCII letters at once (`baz`) and the negative lookahead `(?!:)` checks the char immediately to the right. It is `:`, so the engine asks itself if there is a way to match the string in a different way. Since `{2,}` can match two chars, not currently matched three, it [*backtracks*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html), and finds a valid match.

Add `a-z` to the lookahead pattern to make sure the char  right after 2 or more lowercase ASCII letters is not a letter and not a colon:

```
[a-z]{2,}(?![a-z:])
             ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtLRvz/2)

If your regex engine supports [*possessive* modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), or [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), you may use them to *prevent backtracking* into the `[a-z]{2,}` subpattern:

```
[a-z]{2,}+(?!:)
(?>[a-z]{2,})(?!:)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtLRvz/3).